# How can I install a single specific package from composer.json, to install developer tools?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm using [PHP_CodeSniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) in my GitLab CI/CD pipelines to ensure my code is properly formatted. The job looks like follows:

```yml
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

coding_standard:
  stage: test
  script:
    - curl -OL https://squizlabs.github.io/PHP_CodeSniffer/phpcs.phar
    - php phpcs.phar --extensions=php .
```

That's working as expected. However, the exact version of the tool is not specified here. So if there's suddenly a new major version of PHP_Codesniffer, the CI/CD job might fail, although my PHP code hasn't changed.
Furthermore, I currently have the tool installed globally on my local machine. In that way, I cannot have a specific version of the tool for every PHP project.

Now I'd like to add the tool as [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) dev-dependency (`require-dev`).

In the CI/CD job I would then call `composer install` instead of downloading the tool via curl.

The problem: That will download *all* packages needlessly, instead of just PHP_Codesniffer and its dependencies. Can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with composer. You can't even install "only the dev dependencies". It's all the dependencies, all the non-dev dependencies, and that's all.

And **it's generally a bad idea** to install this kind of dependency as a *project* dependency, since very easily you can enter in [dependency hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) for reasons beyond your actual application needs. Development tools should not bring that level of complexity and danger to your deployment strategy.

To get around this, you could use something like the [Composer Bin Plugin](https://github.com/bamarni/composer-bin-plugin) to isolate these dependencies and yet install them through composer. Then on CI you'd run `composer install` on this directory only, and run the tool from this location (or symlink it to `bin`, which is what the plugin does when it's installed, but you wouldn't have it installed in CI if you are not installing all the dependencies anyway).

Comment: Thanks, that works! However, that solution leads to another problem. I've added `"post-install-cmd": ["@composer bin all install --ansi"]` to my Composer scripts, so the tools are automatically installed when one installs the project dependencies (for development). But that script will crash when preparing the project for production deployment, because `composer install --no-dev` won't install the Composer Bin Plugin.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you shouldn't use the plugin during CI. Since you are not installing all your dependencies on CI, you cannot depend on the plugin. In CI just `cd` to the appropriate "bin" dir and run `composer install` there.

Comment: Yes, but the plugin is a dev-dependency of my project. However, that problem is unrelated to this stackoverflow question. Thanks.

Comment: you use the plugin while developing, but once on CI, you no longer use the plugin. On CI, you'll have (e.g.) `vendor-bin/sometool`. You you simply `cd vendor-bin/sometool && composer install`, and the run the tool from there. e.g. `php vendor-bin/csfixer/vendor/firendsofphp/php-cs-fixer`

Comment: I do understand that. But after the `coding_standard` job succeeds, a `build` job is executed where the project is build (install Composer and Node dependencies, compile SASS and JS, etc.). I need to run `composer install --no-dev` there, but the handy `post-install-cmd` script will then fail.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use that  `post-install-cmd` script myself. If I did, I would use `--no-scripts`, and execute whichever scripts I want to run after `install` manually (which come to think about it, is what I do anyway when building projects).

Answer (score 0):

Why not download any tagged version from Github through https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/releases, like https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/releases/download/3.6.0/phpcs.phar?

Using a PHAR is better than installing such stuff using Composer, as you might install other incompatible dependencies that way (this is not the case with phpcs, but other tools like phpmd install other dependencies from Symfony)

Comment: When downloading a tagged version, I cannot profit from a version range. Version 3.6.1 or 3.7.0 wouldn't be automatically installed. I would have to keep an eye on the versions and update the URL manually. Furthermore, I would have to place a phpcs.phar in every project directory, if I want a specific version of the tool for each project. What do you mean I could install incompatible dependencies when getting the tool via Composer?